# onUploadProgress with axios only shows isTrusted: true

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, axios

I am uploading a file to an API server (hosted locally for testing) using axios.post. The file uploads and everything else is dandy, however when Chrome calls onUploadProgress, the progressEvent only has this value:

```
{"isTrusted":true}
```

Given I haven't seen anybody else run into this issue, I am convinced it is a problem with my code.

```
async uploadFileAsync(event) {
  try {
    if (event && event.target && event.target.files && event.target.files.length === 1) {
      this.downloadPercentage = 0;
      this.showProgress = true;

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);

      let response = await axios.post(
        this.apiUrl,
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          },
          onUploadProgress(progressEvent) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify(progressEvent));
            window.console.log('foo');
            this.downloadPercentage = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
          }
        });

      // snip
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    // snip
  }
  finally {
    this.showProgress = false;
  }
}
```

My console output looks like this:

```
{"isTrusted":true}
foo
{"isTrusted":true}
foo
{"isTrusted":true}
foo
{"isTrusted":true}
foo
...
```

I tried throttling my network with Chrome to make sure that isn't the issue, and onUploadProgress is called hundreds of times while it is uploading, and the upload eventually succeeds. But my progressEvent has no status in it.

Anybody know what would cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody else suffers from this, the solution is to change the function definition to this:

```js
onUploadProgress: function onUploadProgress(progressEvent) {
  this.downloadPercentage = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
}.bind(this)
```

The key there is the `.bind(this)`. This is another case of the `this` pointing to the wrong object, and I needed to bind the callback function to the correct instance.

Also, I don't understand why JSON.stringify() sometimes misses properties on some objects, but all of them can be discovered by explicitly looking for them. For instance:

```js
for (let prop in progressEvent) {
  let val = progressEvent[prop];
  window.console.log(`progressEvent[${prop}] <${typeof(val)}> = ${val}`);
}
```

I hope this helps somebody else.